# How to use inferencing for searching on similar columns in documents via marklogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Suppose I have two xml documents :
Document 1:

```
<item>
  <item_id> 001 </item_id>
  <color>blue</color>
</item>
```

Document 2:

```
<item>
  <item_ref_id>abc</item_ref_id>
  <color>blue</color>
</item>
```

Now for inferencing, I will define a triple as:

`<item_ref_id> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> <item_id>`

If I write a SPARQL query for fetching document2 with `<item_id>` = abc, it should work.
Is this possible via inferencing, how can we do this kind of stuff through MarkLogic.
What all triples are needed to achieve this?

Updating the approach which i used as:

```
 import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at         
 "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

 declare namespace s = "http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#";

for $doc in sem:query-results-serialize(sem:sparql( "SELECT ?s WHERE 
{?s <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>    
<productId>}"),"xml")//s:uri/text()

return cts:element-value-query(xs:QName($doc), '001')
```

The result which i get from this is:
    cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("","id"), "001", ("lang=en"), 1)
    cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("","productId"), "001", ("lang=en"), 1)

I have few questions regarding this:
1. Is my approach correct for solving this scenario which i have mentioned above ?
2. I am not able to use the result of sparql query and expand the query for searching the document, can you please update what i am doing wrong in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However, you can also leverage the sameAs triple in MarkLogic document search. While processing a search call, you could identify searches based on `item_id`. You could then expand `item_id` using values returned from the SPARQL call alike:

```
select * { ?s <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> <item_id> }
```

And then run the expanded search query.

-- addition --

The code you shared in your updated question is almost there, you have successfully extrapolated from productId to id. You only need to wrap the element queries into an and-query, and pass it to cts:search. Something like:

```
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at         
 "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

declare namespace s = "http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#";

let $qnames :=
  for $id in sem:query-results-serialize(sem:sparql( "SELECT ?s WHERE 
    {?s <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs     
      <item_id>}"),"xml")//s:uri/text()

  return xs:QName($id)

return cts:search(collection(), cts:element-value-query($qnames, '001'))
```

HTH!

Comment: **And then run the expanded search query.** , how to do this as i tried many stuff regarding this, i am able to find same as values for '<item_id>', but how to use it for further search to map matching values with **abc**.

Comment: How to create triples to link item_id with value 001 and  item_ref_id with abc, and link item_id and item_ref_id with document, to actally get document while searching with item_id abc.

Comment: Regarding expanded search: it kind of depends on how you search, but you would basically take the cts:query, and change it. `cts:element-query(xs:Name("item_id"), "abc")` would be changed into `cts:element-query((xs:Name("item_id"), xs:Name("item_ref_id"))`. Once you have the expanded query, you can search like you would have normally done..

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies, but i am not able to solve it with `cts:element-query`, i have updated the question again with what i have tried with expand query, can you please update

Comment: This solution works only with item_id 001 as mentioned  in above example, but not for item_id abc when passed, do we have to change something for this, when the triple query returns multiple results it fails. For trying this way of extended query i have added two documents and just created a single triple as item_id <sameas> item_ref_id.

Comment: Ah, silly me. I had a so-called shotgun OR-query in mind. That is a element-value-query with a sequence of QNames. Let me fix the code..

Answer (score 1):

You can only inference over RDF data, so you would have to convert the XML structure to triples. You could then define a rule like this:

```
rule "item_ref_id" construct {
  ?s <item_id> ?o
} {
  ?s <item_ref_id> ?o
}
```

And after that you only need to select the rule when running SPARQL to make use of it.

HTH!

Comment: Regarding your comment on the other answer _"How to create triples to link item_id with value 001 and item_ref_id with abc, and link item_id and item_ref_id with document, to actally get document while searching with item_id abc."_: You could convert your XML to RDF/XML, and load that. [Example 8 from the RDF/XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/#example8) might give you some ideas..

Answer (score 0):

I have added relationship for the above mentioned scenario in this way:

(item1 uri)---> has unique --> id ---> same as <--- productid <---- has unique <--- (item2 uri)

item_id ---> (hasValue-def) ---> 001

item_ref_id---> (hasValue-def) ----> abc

After adding the following triples i could search the item using item_id for both the items, using inferencing as:

```
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";
declare namespace s = "http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#";


for $doc in sem:query-results-serialize(
sem:sparql("SELECT * WHERE {?s <has-unique-key as#>/<https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-owl-ref-20021112/#hasValue-def>/<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>*  <001>}"),     "xml")//s:uri/text()
return fn:doc($doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

@grtjn

I have got the solution for that fix, which resolves query to search for both id's, please check this:

```
Document1:

<item>
  <item_id> 001 </item_id>
  <color>blue</color>
</item>

Document2:

<item>
  <item_ref_id>abc</item_ref_id>
  <color>blue</color>
</item>

Triple:

<sem:triple>
  <sem:subject>item_ref_id</sem:subject>
  <sem:predicate>http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs</sem:predicate>
  <sem:object>item_id</sem:object>
</sem:triple>
```

With this structure above, i run the following query (modified from the solution), and it resolves the document for both id's with item_id:

```
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" 
at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";
declare namespace s = "http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#";

for $id in  sem:query-results-serialize(
sem:sparql( "SELECT ?s WHERE {?s <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> <item_id>}"),"xml")//s:uri/text() 


return cts:search(collection(),cts:and-query((
cts:element-value-query(xs:QName($id), '001'))
))
```

It works if i pass 'abc' too for the search.

Thanks for the idea of how to use this, it helped me resolve this problem.

Comment: This code will run a separate search for each $id value, that is a little inefficient, and could cause duplicate results. The separate search cancels the effect of the and-query as well, but this made me realize I made a mistake in my answer. The AND should have been an OR. My updated answer shows how you can do an OR on multiple id's efficiently..